# NodeJS serve media file (video and audio)

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a problem with NodeJs serving media files. The fileserving works in firefox but Chrome and IE have some trouble.

Chrome can only play the file once and controls are not working.

IE plays the file multiple times but controls are not working.

For both of them I had to implement a workarround, so that they will download the file completly, streaming doesn't work. I also compared the request headers of chrome and firefox, they seem to be identical.

Here is my code:

```
serveFile = (req, res)->
  viewType = req.params.viewType
  viewName = req.params.folder
  fileType =  req.params.fileType
  fileName = req.params.fileName

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

  if fileType is 'image'
    file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "../../../temporary_files/" + viewType + "s/" +         viewName + "/ressources/" + fileType + "s/" + fileName )
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif' })
    res.end(file, 'binary')
  else
    if req.headers["user-agent"].indexOf('Chrome') is -1 and  req.headers.range isnt undefined
      console.log req.headers.range
      console.log "-------"
      console.log req.headers
      fs.readFile(__dirname + "../../../temporary_files/" + viewType + "s/" + viewName + "/ressources/" + fileType + "s/" + fileName, (error, content)->
        if error
          res.writeHead 500
          res.end '<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>'
        else
          range = req.headers.range
          total = content.length
          parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
          partialstart = parts[0]
          partialend = parts[1]
          start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
          end = if partialend then parseInt(partialend, 10) else total
          chunksize = (end-start)
          res.writeHead(206, {
            "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
            "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Length": chunksize,
            "Content-Type": fileType + "/" + (if fileName.split(".")[1] is 'mp3' then 'mpeg' else 'mp4')
          })
          res.end(content.slice(start, end))
      )
    else
      console.log "here"
      file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "../../../temporary_files/" + viewType + "s/" + viewName + "/ressources/" + fileType + "s/" + fileName )
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': fileType + "/" + (if fileName.split(".")[1] is 'mp3' then 'mpeg' else 'mp4') })
      res.end(file, 'binary')
```

This really drive me nuts. I have no clue how to fix it. I tried preload-tag in the media tag with no result.

Would be really thankful for help.